# Capacitor Sizing for A Full Wave Bridge Rectifier?

Tags: capacitor, dc, ripple, full-bridge

Building my understanding of the issue from ([First PSU - need help with capacitor size](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/144870/first-psu-need-help-with-capacitor-size)) (especially the comments/ripple wiki/several capacitor sizing webpages) the calculation for rectifying a full wave bridge rectifier at 50A 16V should be:

$$\frac{50A}{2 * 60Hz * 2V (Ripple)} = .208333$$
Converting from F to uF, I get $$.208333*10^6=208,333uF$$

So I should get a filter capacitor close to 0.21000uF at greater than 30V (Peak/rounded/safety margin)? This is my first time doing such calculations, are there any glaring errors? I know that the person several people struggled with some of the complexity, and I'm not sure if my interpretation of some of the variables (particularly dV) is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Err, no, I think your last step there is off.

$$
\frac{50\text{A}}{2\cdot 60\text{Hz}\cdot 2\text{V}} = 0.2083\text{F} = 208333\mu\text{F}
$$

That's a *huge* capacitor. <strike>Or, more likely, *huge bank* of capacitors.</strike> (Edit: as it turns out, there are plenty of capacitors > 200mF and > 35V. However, they are expensive, and about the size of a Mason jar.)

Are you sure you want to be designing a 50A bridge rectifier? There are likely better ways to design a 50A AC-DC converter.

Also, how crucial is the 16V output? I'm guessing the 16V accounts for voltage drop on a regulator, so does 15V regulated out work? Because there are power supplies that can provide 15V @ 50+ A (see [this XP Power PSU](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/xp-power/HDS800PS15/1470-2688-ND/5023630) for example).

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed that it was one more digit off than I thought. That sucks. Order of magnitude difference. I'm not sure what method is best for AC to DC conversion at that high of a current. I can increase the ripple size to 5V & decrease the current to 40A which makes the system more manageable at 66,666uF.

Comment: Does it absolutely have to be a monolithic supply? It'd be a lot easier to build a few ~25A power supplies. Also, see my edits.

Comment: Actually, I've finagled together a microwave oven transformer (rewound for 16V) and am using it with a bridge rectifier to run 40-50A DC through various electrochemical projects. (Which depend critically on current) So far, I've only paid $10 for the bridge and about $5 in connectors. (I found the MOT on the street) It works rather well (for about 5 minutes before it gets too hot), but doesn't produce a reasonably constant voltage, and currently only uses the absolute value of the sin function.